# Date picker can't use custom format

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datepicker

In my WPF-Project I have a DatePicker, but if I output it, it gives me 2 Nov 2018.

But I need it as 2018-10-2 because I want it for SQL.

I tryed this code:

```
dpStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

But Visual Studio says there's no Format for Date-Picker.

What do I do wrong/is there an easy way to transform the DatePicker format to SQL?

Comment: can you share your view code. actual textbox. how you bind it

Comment: You should store the data as a datetime and not as a string in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I need it as 2018-10-2 because I want it for SQL.

The `DateTime` value stored by the `DatePicker` control has no specific format. You may apply a format when you convert the value to a `string` though:

```
string formattedDate = dpStart.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But you should really consider passsing the actual `DateTime` value rather than a formatted `string` to your data access layer.

Comment: Thanks, how can I give it the DateTime Value instead of a string? My query string is built like this:

`string query = $"INSERT INTO Film (ProdTitel, Titel, Beginn, Abgeschlossen, Kategorie, Notiz) VALUES(\"{PTitel}\", \"{Titel}\", \"{Beginn}\", \"{End}\", \"{Kat}\", \"{Notiz}\");";`

Comment: @TimothyLukasH.: You should use parameters. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                     Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy', 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use above code to change the display format of the date of the DatePicker control to "dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: You can write this code in App.xaml, so that all DatePicker control contained in application will display the date in above mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it something like

```
 DateTime dpStartDate = (DateTime)dpStart.SelectedDate;
 string result = dpStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```